# How to automatize a ssh tunnel over various hosts?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, webserver

I have the following problem: I need to access a local webserver from a bunch of machines (let's say PC-01, PC-02 ... , PC-XX) that I can only access over a ssh bridge (PC-SSH).

I solved the ssh problem of connecting to this various machines by adding a rule on my sshconfig file:

```
Host PC-*  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa  
    User username  
    ProxyJump PC-SSH
```

With this I can just `ssh PC-X` withouth any (manual) jumps.
Currently, to access the pages on PC-XX, I need to do a `ssh -L port:PC-XX:port PC-SSH`, but I need to do this manually to every PC-XX and to every port.

What I want is to be able to simply go to my browser and go to some url like `PC-05:4040` and access the page on this machine on this port. Is this possible?

Thank you all for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a proxy auto-config ([PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)) file and a SOCKS proxy.
You would then set up the forwarding in your `~/.ssh/config` file to forward all requests on some local port through a SOCKS tunnel to the remote machine, and have the PAC file route requests matching the host name through that tunnel.

For example, a PAC file with content:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

  alert("url" + url);

  if (shExpMatch(url,"*myhostname*")) {
    alert("Using special tunnel");
    return "SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:9999";
  }

  // All other requests go directly to the WWW:
  return "DIRECT";

}
```

coupled with an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file such as:

```
Host PH-*
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa  
     User username  
     ProxyJump PC-SSH
     DynamicForward 9999
```

when you execute `ssh -Nf PH-05` would open local port `9999` and forward all local traffic on that port through your `ssh` tunnel to `PH-05`. The options `-Nf` puts the process into the background, but the config file will open this forward for *any* `ssh` connection to `PH-*`, so you may prefer to create a specific alias for just the tunnel, e.g., `PH-05-tunnel`, and only have the `DynamicForward` included there.  Alternatively, if `PH-SSH` can access `PH-05:4040`, then you could just create a `PH-SSH-tunnel` rule, and set the hostname to `PH-SSH`, eliminating the `ProxyJump` part.

Then, depending on your setup (`firefox` has proxy settings in the browser, `chrome`/`chromium` use system proxy settings) you tell your proxy manager to use the PAC file and then you can point your browser to, e.g., `PH-05:4040` and your browser should render this page.

Comment: It looks like this method actually creates another problem, since I need to access various ports on the same PC-XX machine sometimes. Alongside this, I need to run a SSH command anyways, so it seems just like a `ssh -L port1:PC-XX:port2 PC-SSH`

Comment: Can you clarify what "creates another problem" means, because the method listed here *should* allow you to connect to `PH-05:1234` without any change, i.e., should satisfy your "need to access various ports on the same PC-XX machine".